# git branch not showing branches in terminal?

Tags: command-line, git

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and Git 2.7.4.

I just did `git init` and then `git branch` but nothing appears at all:

```
~/node/uui$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/alex/node/uui/.git/
~/node/uui$ git branch
~/node/uui$
```

I'm really puzzled. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to make at least one commit before you can see the `master` branch listed by the `git branch` command.

Answer (score 3):

Try this command   `git branch --show-current`